Always on availability group removing nodes
We have a SQL 2014 enterprise with 4 node availability group database with 2 Synchronous commit , 1 read only Asynchronous for reporting and 1 DR asynchronous.
Due to space shortage we need to remove some nodes. Since the reports points out to the Asynchronous reporting server can we remove 2 nodes ( 1 Synchronous replica and 1 DR) and make the Reporting server in Synchronous mode and keep it read only.
The cluster will then have 2 nodes both in synchronous mode with 1 disk witness for the quorum.
This setup will thus have no Disaster recovery server as it is temporary .
I will appreciate if someone can advice whether I can have this setup or if there is a better work around.

"can we...make the Reporting server in Synchronous mode and keep it read only." - Not sure what you're asking. All secondary replicas in AlwaysOn Availability Groups are read-only. Only 1 replica, the primary, can be writable at any given time. It has nothing to do with the Availability Mode you choose for those secondary replicas. Even with your current setup, your secondary replica that is currently using the Synchronous-Commit Availability Mode is still read-only because it's a secondary replica.

We are using 2 nodes in our company and we are using secondary node for reporting with Synchronous commitand readable secondary Yes
